# Slide down/Slide Up animation on changing visibility of a Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` in my `View` whose visibility is set as `GONE`. I need to provide a slide down translation and also set the visibility as `VISIBLE` for the `RelativeLayout` over the `ListView` on button press and Slide up animation on button press by.

```
    replyMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //slideToBottom(replyLayout);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reply pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,replyLayout.getHeight());
            animate.setDuration(1000);
            animate.setFillAfter(true);
            replyLayout.startAnimation(animate);
            replyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(replyFlag){
            replyMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.reply_active);
            replyFlag = true;
            }else{
                replyMessage.setImageResource(R.drawable.reply_img);
                replyFlag = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: add your code what you tried??

Comment: I need to find a way to slide up and down the relative layout on button click